# Two popular question badges awarded for the same question

Tags: bug, badges

Hopefully, this hasn't been reported yet, but I couldn't find it on meta so far.
Today, I have received two "popular question" badges at the same time for the same question and they both seem to add up to my total badges. I strongly assume this is a bug and hopefully it can be reproduced somehow.

The question I am talking about can be found  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964702/what-is-the-actual-use-of-array-convertall-compared-to-e-g-looping-through-the).

Comment: Congrats for the badges :-)

Comment: [Awarded 5 minutes apart](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=1092381). It *is* weird...

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for [Meta.SE] now.

Comment: Okay, thank you first of all for the replies. And thank you for the congrats on the badges (=
@minitech Do you think I should post it on Meta Stack Exchange now? I wasn't completely sure about this, since the bug (at least for me) specifically happened on SO

Comment: No, it’s okay. There are still plenty of bug reports here, but I think this (and most bugs) probably applies to all sites.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer. Hopefully, this will be fixed and I will lose my badge.

Comment: Looking forward this same behavior for "Great Question" badge :)

Comment: That's the first time I hear someone saying "Hopefully ... I will lose my badge" :-)

Comment: We're looking into the issue. In the meantime, I've manually deleted your duplicate badge. ;)

Comment: @Haney Thank you for the answer and thanks for deleting the badge (; No reason to be obsessed with badges. In the end we all (hopefully) want a well functioning site...